# Custom Error Handling In @Preauthorize false return or exception

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-boot

I have @preauthorize for security purposes but when this function is returning false then i am getting

> Access is denied

in response thru Spring. How to handle the exception as per my own implementation?

```html
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#cookie,'balance')")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create your custom exception handler.
In this example, you are in a REST environment, that's why I put a ResponseEntity as return object. But you can return whatever you want depending on your context.

```
@ControllerAdvice
@RestController
public class MyResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(AccessDeniedException.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<CustomResponseObject> handleAccessDeniedException(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
        //code here
        return new ResponseEntity<>(...);
    }
}
```